# Find credit card numbers and replace characters at set positions

Tags: sed, replace, position, credit-card, anonymize

I have a file that contains credit card numbers (16 characters), I want to find them and replace everything with "X" apart from the first 6 and last 4 numbers.

```
sed -i 's/\([345]\{1\}[0-9]\{3\}\|6011\)\{1\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{4\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{2\}[-]\?[0-9]\{2\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{1,4\}/\XXXXXX/g' foobar.csv
```

Will easily find all credit cards contained in the file and replace them with "XXXX"

But I want to find the credit cards and replace only characters 7-12 of the string with "X", so the file will contain credits which are masked like this 123456XXXXXX7890.

Sample input line:

```
jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 4548640040302006 in the morning jimmy
```

Sample output line:

```
jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 454864XXXXXX2006 in the morning jimmy
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Sample input line:
"jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 4548640040302006 in the morning jimmy"


Sample output line:
"jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 454864XXXXXX2006 in the morning jimmy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed to anonymize credit card numbers:

```
sed -i 's/\(\([345]\{1\}[0-9]\{3\}\|6011\)\{1\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{2\}\)[0-9]\{2\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{2\}[-]\?[0-9]\{2\}[ -]\?\([0-9]\{1,4\}\)/\1XXXXXX\3/g' file
```

Input:

```
jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 4548640040302006 in the morning jimmy
jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 454864XXXXXX2006 in the morning jimmy
```

Output to file:

```
jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 454864XXXXXX2006 in the morning jimmy
jam peanut boat handbag on the shore in Tuesday 454864XXXXXX2006 in the morning jimmy
```